# load balancing multiplie services linux

Tags: linux, load-balancing

I have setup multiple servers,

One of them is a windows server running `team speak`.

The other is a game server with `csgo(counter strike global offensive)`

and lastly, one running an `apache server`.

I will use my `vserver` as `load balancer`.

I want to load balance all traffic over the `vserver` but without redirects, so that clients can connect to my `vserver` using multiple games and gaming services.

It has been suggested to use something like `vpn` or `iptables` but didn't get a good answer so I'm asking here..

I am already using pound for web services and now I will do the same things for my games and services...
How I can do this?

Another thing that I  would like to do is white-list on every server only the `vserver`, so no client can do an direct connection to the servers

HERE IS THE ACTUAL SYSTEM:

```
[CLIENT]←-(ts3)--→[ts3 Server](different ip)
[CLIENT]←-(apache)--→[apache Server](different ip)
[CLIENT]←-(game)--→[game Server](different ip)
```

HERE IS MY PLANNED SYSTEM:

```
                              (one IP)
[CLIENT]←-(ts3/apache/game)--→[vserver]←-(apache via pound)-→[apache Server]
                                  ↑
                                  |←-(Ts3 traffic)-→[ts3 Server]
                                  |←-(game traffic)-→[game Server]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if load balancing is something that you want here. To my knowledge, load balancing is used to share load between servers doing _identical tasks_. Since your three servers serve different functions, the existence of your `vserver` creates an unnecessary complication and possible bottleneck in your system.

Comment: oh yes i understand but what i can do now ?

Comment: If you are mainly looking for security, consider putting a device in front of your servers and just do some `nat`ting to keep your application servers from being directly accessed. Just forward the specific ports that you need and you will be able to configure controlled access as well.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to enable your users to use the same address for each service, I would instead get a domain name and set a subdomain for each service. eg:

```
ts3.gameservers.com --- TeamSpeak3
csgo.gameservers.com --- CSGO
www.gameservers.com / gameservers.com --- your Apache web server.
```

Comment: yeah but my target is it to force the traffic over the v server ...

Comment: @ProJaCore It will if the VServer is the host of your domain.  Ie. all traffic to `gameservers.com` will be on a virtual host,  Google Plex Control Pannel or cpanel to begin research.  Redraw Your Diagram from your question with the Apache WebServer in front of the diagram, to see what we mean.  I'd draw it here but this isn't my answer.